# Zend: How to create module with command line?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

When I try to create module:

```
zf.sh create module user
```

It shows the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_Loader in /var/www/myproject/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 31
```

How to avoid this error ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you run command from project root folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I commented out the following line in **application.ini** and everything is working..

```
;includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

**Help Source:**

- http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=813

Comment: Indeed We are including our library path twice, on public/index.php and on our configs/application.ini - and we then receive that error.